# TooManyConstructorsFoundException in Power mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

I have tried to mock JSONArray and also tried by suppressing constructor. But none of the solutions are working for me.

```
 JSONArray mockJSONArray=PowerMokcito.mock(JSONArray.class);, 

 whenNew(JSONArray.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockJSONArray);
 whenNew(JSONArray.class).withArguments(anyObject()).thenReturn(mockJSONArray);
```

Can anyone help on this issue ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution can be identified from the exception log itself.
'please specify the argument parameter types'.

Exception trace :

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyConstructorsFoundException: 
Several matching constructors found, please specify the argument parameter types so that PowerMock can determine which method you're referring to.
Matching constructors in class org.json.JSONArray were:
org.json.JSONArray( java.lang.Object.class )
org.json.JSONArray( java.util.Collection.class )
```

Below is the example how to use parameter types when multiple constructors are there.

```
    @Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    // Mock JSONArray object with desired value.
    JSONArray mockJSONArray=PowerMockito.mock(JSONArray.class);
    String mockArrayStr = "[ { \"name\" : \"Tricky solutions\" } ]";
    PowerMockito.when(mockJSONArray.getString(0)).thenReturn(mockArrayStr);

    // mocking constructor
    PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONArray.class).withParameterTypes(String.class)
            .withArguments(Matchers.any()).thenReturn(mockJSONArray);

}

@Test
public void testJSONArray() throws Exception {

    String str = "[ { \"name\" : \"kswaughs\" } ]";

    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(str);

    System.out.println("result is : "+arr.getString(0));

}

Output :
result is : [ { "name" : "Tricky solutions" } ]
```